# C# Delegate funkiness

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm experiencing some weird issues with a delegate method.

I have class ClassA : System.Web.Ui.Page
class ClassB : ClassA
class UserPage : ClassB

Delegate FuncA = UserPageObject.SomeMethod

When UserPage reloads after, saving and restoring it's state, the delegate is invoked via

```
protected override UserPage.Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){  
//Calling the B.Page_Load method  
base.Page_Load(sender, e);  
//Do other stuff  
}  
protected virtual void B.Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){  
FuncA.Invoke();  
}
```

Edited to Add FuncA initialization:

```
public delegate void FuncA();

[Serializable]
public class PageState
{
public Complete FuncA { get; set; }
}

PageStateObject.FuncA = SomeUserPageObject.SomeMethod;
```

FuncA makes some changes to UserPage controls, appears to act on the correct object and otherwise executes successfully and UserPage is correct. When B.PageLoad returns and UserPage.Page_Load starts executing the changes have completely disappeared.

This doesn't appear to make sense and I've stumped our senior architect on this one, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Whoa there, you're calling base implementations of autowired event handlers (`Page_Load()`) instead of protected overridable members (`OnLoad()`). The latter is responsible for calling the former. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: `UserPage.SomeMethod` is a static method?

Comment: That's only my current attempt.  I've placed the FuncA.Invoke() call in several different handlers. With similar results.

Comment: Nope, not static either.

Comment: Can you post the exact initialization of / assignment to `FuncA`?

Comment: if not static then you cant assign `UserPage.SomeMethod` to delegate. It has to be `SomeUserPageObject.SomeMethod`. Please post correct code.

Comment: My oversight on the code, corrected now.

Comment: that is the thing - what is `UserPageObject` now - who created it , how did you get a reference to it? Most likely you are updating a wrong instance of `UserPage` hence your changes _seem to_ disappear in the correct instance which you should have updated.

Comment: The `UserPageObject` is the standard one created on a call to the server. The `FuncA` delegate is stored it a separate object with other pagestate info in Session. So that when we come back to the page the transaction can be completed. So a page1 redirects to page2 to do something and then back to page1.

I may have just answered my own question, because the delegate assignment probably keeps the reference to the original object created on the first request, but a new object would be created when we return to the page, right?

Comment: What are you really storing in the Session? Your object that will execute the code or only the data?

Comment: I was storing a delegate reference to a method in the original UserPage object. What I forgot was that a new Page object is created with every request.  So on redirecting back to UserPage, reloading PageState and executing the delegate method, it was acting on the previous object not the current one being processed and rendered.  Short version: needed to use Reflection instead of a delegate.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that FuncA is delegate and therefore B.page_load returns immediately without waiting for FunA to return. My suspicion is that FuncA and userpage.page_load are trying to change the same object at the same time and hence override each other. Try running them synchronously.